# Display only portion of screen on monitor

Tags: windows-7, display, crop

I have an application that displays live wait-time information, however it does not have provisions for full screen mode or similar. As a result, we have a monitor displaying both wait time and the application's toolbars, etc.

Is there a way to crop the screen area so that only a portion of the app is displayed on the monitor? I am running Windows 7.

Comment: It depends on the application you are running not the operating system.

Comment: Are you talking about cropping screen area of screen for Win 7 real estate or just for this app?